# Mono sorts different on different machines

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have a simple sorting issue using mono...
If I run the following code on Mac and Windows I get a different result:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var testArray = new string[]
        {
        "PȺFftFyaheâµ", "P6ZĳTµȺut"
        }.OrderBy(t => t);

        foreach (var item in testArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Result windows

```
P6ZĳTµȺut
PȺFftFyaheâµ
```

Result Mac

```
PȺFftFyaheâµ
P6ZĳTµȺut
```

Does anyone has a clue how this is possible and what we can do to fix it?

Thanks the fix was a string comparer

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testArray = new string[] { "PȺFftFyaheâµ", "P6ZĳTµȺut" }.OrderBy(t =>  t, StringComparer.Ordinal);
        foreach (var item in testArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to be expected, given differences in culture. From the [`string.CompareTo(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture. For more information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see `System.Globalization.CompareOptions`.

To make sure the code behaves the same way on multiple systems, you can either ensure you use the same culture on all systems, or specify a culture-insensitive comparison (e.g. `StringComparer.Ordinal`) as a second argument to `OrderBy`.

Comment: We actually had to use InvarientCulture instead of Ordinal.
It was giving some problems with Arabic characters, any clue why?

Comment: @Frederiek: Well that on its own doesn't give me enough information to help, I'm afraid - `Ordinal` should be entirely culture-free, as far as I'm aware. Of course, it depends on what "problems" you were seeing..

Comment: Ah ok, all we do is generate a Directory structure of files and folders. These files and folders are created randomly from `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789-+!@#µ¶±ÆßàáâãĲĳȺضضظ"` 
It works now, but it is indeed strange that `Ordinal` gives different results